# create event subscriptions in RDS with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Does CloudFormation support or have the ability to create DB event subscriptions(RDS)?
I failed to find any reference in AWS document...

Thanks

Comment: I've been looking for this ability myself but don't think its available yet. Here is a workaround by Dean Wilson:
https://github.com/deanwilson/aws-scripts/blob/master/create-rds-sns-association.md

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of CloudFormation, at the time of this writing, actually supports performing this by creating a ["AWS::RDS::EventSubscription" resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-eventsubscription.html) in your stack.

> ```
> "myEventSubscription": {
>   "Type": "AWS::RDS::EventSubscription",
>   "Properties": {
>     "EventCategories": ["configuration change", "failure", "deletion"],
>     "SnsTopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:example-topic",
>     "SourceIds": ["db-instance-1", { "Ref" : "myDBInstance" }],
>     "SourceType":"db-instance",
>     "Enabled" : false
>   }
> }
> ```